# JNDI modifyAttributes and NameNotFoundError

Tags: java, jndi

I have a weird problem with LdapContext.modifyAttributes(name,mods) method.
It gives me a NameNotFoundException, even though that object exists on the same path.
(I already checked with a small piece of code which returns *distinguishedName*s)
Here is my sample code;

```
ModificationItem[] mods = new ModificationItem[1]; 
            for(Group g: this.groups)
            {
                mods[0] = new ModificationItem(DirContext.REPLACE_ATTRIBUTE,new BasicAttribute("member", g.getMembers()));
                this.context.modifyAttributes("cn="+g.getGroupName()+", ou=OU_MyGroups", mods);
            }
```

This is my connection strings if it helps:

```
this.setConnectionUrl("ldap://10.77.162.187:389/dc=C4test");
```

Also, I tried to get attributes from same object, using same name string.

```
Attributes attr = this.context.getAttributes("cn="+g.getGroupName()+", ou=OU_MyGroups");
```

And it worked just fine. 
So I'm out of ideas right now.

And this is my stack trace:

```
Exception in thread "main" javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: [LDAP: error code 32 - 00000525: NameErr: DSID-031A0F80, problem 2001 (NO_OBJECT), data 0, best match of: ''

; remaining name 'cn=INSAN KAYNAKLARI DIREKTORLUGU, ou=OU_MyGroups'
    at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtx.mapErrorCode(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtx.processReturnCode(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtx.processReturnCode(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtx.c_modifyAttributes(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.jndi.toolkit.ctx.ComponentDirContext.p_modifyAttributes(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.jndi.toolkit.ctx.PartialCompositeDirContext.modifyAttributes(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.jndi.toolkit.ctx.PartialCompositeDirContext.modifyAttributes(Unknown Source)
    at javax.naming.directory.InitialDirContext.modifyAttributes(Unknown Source)
    at com.carrefour.activeDirectory.GroupUpdater.updateGroups(GroupUpdater.java:140)
    at com.carrefour.activeDirectory.GroupUpdater.<init>(GroupUpdater.java:129)
    at com.carrefour.activeDirectory.ActiveDirectoryUpdater.main(ActiveDirectoryUpdater.java:101)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What's the DN of this.context()? If it is 'ou=OU_MyGroups', you don't need to specify that again in modifyAttributes(). In general you only need to specify the RDN of the item to modify relative to the context you are calling modifyAttributes() on.

Comment: Complete distinguished name of the group that i'm trying to modify is "cn=groupName, ou=OU_MyGroups, dc=C4test". Also using the same distinguishedName in getAttributes method works just fine but when I use it on modifyAttributes there is a problem. There is another thread with the same problem http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2317102/jndi-add-users-to-groups-with-ads but no clear solutions to the problem.

Comment: @isail but what's the answer to my question? What's the DN of the context you are calling modifyAttributes() on? And are all the DNs in members() accurate?

Comment: Thanks, I figured it out. It turns out it wasn't the group DN that raised this error. It was the members' DN that I was trying to add to group.